# Function Name Variability with Pointer in Struct

Tags: c

The pointers function declarations in the following snippets of code allows me to vary the names of each function inside the struct, correct? This is merely hypothetical, so the names are of no consequence yet.

**Header File**

```
typedef struct
{
    bool (*enabled)(uint32_void);
    void (*start)(uint32_t);
    void (*stop)(uint32_t);
    bool (*expired)(void);
} battle_star_gallactica;
```

**C File**

```
static bool Battle_v0_enabled (void) { ... }
static void Battle_v0_start (uint32_t) { ... }
static void Battle_v0_stop (uint32_t) { ... }
static bool Battle_v0_stop (void) { ... }

const battle_star_gallactica battle_v0 =
{
    enabled,
    start,
    stop,
    expired
};
...
```

**One Example Use**

```
battle_v0.start(1000);
```

The C file snippet would be repeated for other versions (e.g. v1 or v2 instead of v0).

How does this work?

**EDIT**

Corrected code:

**Header File**

```
typedef struct
{
    bool (*enabled)(uint32_void);
    void (*start)(uint32_t);
    void (*stop)(uint32_t);
    bool (*expired)(void);
} battle_star_gallactica;

extern const battle_star_gallactica battle_v0;
extern const battle_star_gallactica battle_v1;
...
```

**C File**

```
static bool Battle_v0_enabled (void) { ... }
static void Battle_v0_start (uint32_t val) { ... }
static void Battle_v0_stop (uint32_t val) { ... }
static bool Battle_v0_expired (void) { ... }

const battle_star_gallactica battle_v0 =
{
    Battle_v0_enabled,
    Battle_v0_start,
    Battle_v0_stop,
    Battle_v0_expired
};
...
```

**One Example Use**

```
battle_v0.start(1000);
```

Comment: "So say we all" -- meaning?

Comment: @Biff - You've *watched* the new "Battlestar Galactica" series, right?

Comment: Haha, no. I heard it on "The Office". Good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  But you have a few issues:

1) Battle_v0_stop is defined twice
2) When initing `battle_v0` you need to prefix values with `Battle_v0_`

You could then do:

```
battle_v0.enabled()
```

But I would have currnet  `battle star galactic` and use it:

```
const battle_star_gallactica bsg = battle_v0;
bgs.enabled()
```

Comment: Is there a name for the manner in which the pointers were used? I was going to read more about it in a C book.

Comment: I simply call them `function pointers`. see http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer

Comment: Do the names of the pointers even matter? Could I, for instance, only have `void (*)(uint32_t)` for the first function pointer?

Comment: You do need a name for fucntion pointer.  How else would you reference it?

Comment: You should not have changed the code that you posted.  Now other readers will not be able to understand my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have no functions named `enabled`, `start`, and so on. When initializing an object with function pointers, pass a pointer to the actual function name (i.e. `Battle_v0_start`). That said, it is important to notice that your types do not match. It should be `Battle_v0_start(uint32_t)`, not `void`.

But yes, after being properly initialized, you will be able to simply call `your_obj.your_struct_function_name(your_arguments, ...)`. In your case `battle_v0.start(1000)` will call `Battle_v0_start` (if you pass this function to the pointer). You can think of this like most other pointer types.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the target function to each of your function pointers, such as

```
battle_v0.enabled = Battle_V0_enabled;
battle_v0.start   = Battle_V0_start;
// etc.
```

or

```
const battle_star_galactica battle_v0 = {
    Battle_V0_enabled,
    Battle_V0_start,
    Battle_V0_stop,
    Battle_V0_expired
};
```

Then you can call the functions through the pointer:

```
battle_v0.start(1000);  // or battle_v0.(*start)(1000)
```

will call the `Battle_V0_start` function with a value of 1000.

Note that the function signatures (return type and number/types of arguments) have to match; for example, you declare the function pointer for `start` to take an argument of type `uint32_t`, but `Battle_V0_start` takes no arguments.  One or the other of these needs to change so that they match.

```
void Battle_V0_start(uint32_t val) { ... }
```